Discrepancies in Calorie Data Aggregation Using HealthConnect API
I am using the HealthConnect API to validate aggregated calorie data against manually summed values from individual records. I've implemented a function in Kotlin that fetches daily records and an aggregated sum for each day over the past 30 days. However, I'm consistently finding discrepancies between these two sums.
Here's an example of how I fetch and aggregate the data:
suspend fun validateCaloriesData(healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient) {
    // Time zone and date setup
    val zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault()
    val endTime = Instant.now().atZone(zoneId).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    val startTime = endTime.minusDays(30)

    var currentDay = startTime
    while (currentDay.isBefore(endTime)) {
        val startOfDay = currentDay.toInstant()
        val endOfDay = currentDay.plusDays(1).toInstant()

        val dailyRecords = mutableListOf<Double>()

        try {
            val records = healthConnectClient.readRecords(
                ReadRecordsRequest(
                    recordType = TotalCaloriesBurnedRecord::class,
                    timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startOfDay, endOfDay),
                    pageSize = 2000,
                    pageToken = null,
                    ascendingOrder = true
                )
            )
            records.records.forEach {
                dailyRecords.add(it.energy.inKilocalories ?: 0.0)
            }

            val sumOfDailyRecords = dailyRecords.sum()
            val response = healthConnectClient.aggregate(
                AggregateRequest(
                    metrics = setOf(TotalCaloriesBurnedRecord.ENERGY_TOTAL),
                    timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startOfDay, endOfDay)
                )
            )
            val aggregatedCalories = response[TotalCaloriesBurnedRecord.ENERGY_TOTAL]?.inKilocalories ?: 0.0

            if (sumOfDailyRecords != aggregatedCalories) {
                Log.e("DailyCaloriesValidation", "Discrepancy found on day $currentDay: Manual sum is $sumOfDailyRecords but aggregated is $aggregatedCalories")
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("DailyCaloriesValidation", "Error reading or aggregating calories for day $currentDay: ${e.message}")
        }

        currentDay = currentDay.plusDays(1)
    }
}


And the logs:
E/DailyCaloriesValidation( 8147): Discrepancy found on day 2024-04-13T00:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]: Manual sum is 100.0 but aggregated is 1707.009
E/DailyCaloriesValidation( 8147): Discrepancy found on day 2024-04-10T00:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]: Manual sum is 188.0 but aggregated is 1780.543

EDIT :
Tests using this app provided by Google : https://goo.gle/health-connect-toolbox give the same results.
